# Rewriting CSV file in Python messes up index of rows

Tags: python, list, csv, range

This is my entire project at the moment. The original CSV file has 4 rows with a contacts name, email, and phone information. The "list" "view" and "add" functions work fine until I use the "delete" function. In order to delete the desired line, I put the file in a list, deleted the row the user inputs, and rewrote the list into the CSV file with what appears to be good format.

```
import csv

print("Contact List\n")
print(" list - Display all contacts\n","view - View a contact\n","add - Add a contact\n", "del - Delete a contact\n", "exit - Exit program\n")
def main():
    userCom = input("\nCommand: ")
    if userCom == "list":
        lists()
    elif userCom == "view":
        count()
    elif userCom == "add":
        add()
    elif userCom == "del":
        delete()
    elif userCom == "exit":
        exitt()
    else :
        print("Invaild input, try again")
        main()

def count():
    counter = 1
    with open("contacts.csv") as file:
        number = file.readline()
        for line in file:
            counter = counter +1
    view(counter)

def lists():        
    with open("contacts.csv", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        counter = 0
        for row in reader:
            print(int(counter) + 1, ". ",row[0])
            counter = counter+1
    main()

def view(count):
    num = input("Enter a contact's number to view their information: ")
    while num.isdigit() == False or int(num) < 1 or int(num) > int(count):
        print("Invaild input, try again")
        view(count)
    reader = csv.reader(open("contacts.csv"))
    lines = list(reader)
    print("Name: ",lines[int(num)-1][0],"\nEmail: ",lines[int(num)-1][1],"\nPhone Number: ",lines[int(num)-1][2])
    main()

def add() :
    name = input("Name: ")
    email = input("Email: ")
    phone = input("Phone: ")
    added = [name,",",email,",",phone]
    with open("contacts.csv", "a") as file:
        for item in added:
            file.write(item)
    print(name, " was added.")
    file.close()
    main()

def delete():
    deleted = input("Enter number to delete: ")
    reader = csv.reader(open("contacts.csv"))
    contacts = list(reader)
    del contacts[int(deleted)-1]

    with open("contacts.csv", "w") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(contacts)
    print("Number ",deleted," was deleted.")`enter code here`
    file.close()
    main()


main()
```

When I use delete and try the "list" or "view" features, I get this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\contacts_1.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\contacts_1.py", line 15, in main
    delete()
  File "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\contacts_1.py", line 72, in delete
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\contacts_1.py", line 9, in main
    lists()
  File "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\contacts_1.py", line 35, in lists
    print(int(counter) + 1, ". ",row[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help helps!

Comment: your problem aside, there is another problem here, you call `main()` recursivly, which will crush at some point (usually ~1000 calls) because of StackOverflowError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `row` doesnt contain any line, so it doesn't even have the `0` index.
Yo must check if the list contain something before accessing any item inside:

```
if row:
    print(row[0])
```

As I said in comment, your solution is flawed, because it will overflow the stack at some point. You should use an infinite loop instead of calling the `main` function again and again

```
def main():
    while 1:
        userCom = input("\nCommand: ")
        if userCom == "list":
            lists()
        elif userCom == "view":
            count()
        elif userCom == "add":
            add()
        elif userCom == "del":
            delete()
        elif userCom == "exit":
            exitt()
        else:
            print("Invaild input, try again")
            # main()
```